# Published mercurial repos - links return 404

Tags: mercurial, hgweb

I am able to publish the list of repositories using hgwebdir.cgi on Tomcat. However none of the links on the published repository work. What should the baseurl be set to? I set it to http://host:port/folder where the cgi-bin is right under the folder. The urls dont form correctly (dont have the hgwebdir.cgi in them) and i have no url rewriting setup. Is there some Tomcat configuration needed to get the urls working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I know hgwebdir.cgi should be installed via an HTTP Web server like Apache.
It is not possible to run it under Tomcat: for this reason it is not working.

- install an apache web server (try XAMPP  if you are running under windows)
- Install a python interpreter
- Put the hgwebdir.cgi  under the CGI dir of your apache web server.
- Configure the hgwebdir.cgi so it can find python on PATH
- You can find more information on the mercurial book http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/

Comment: Thanks for the tip daitangio. I installed Apache and configured it... and yes the repository browsing is perfect. I am running into issues with cloning it though, get 500 internal server error with "Bad Header" message in the Apache error logs. Did you see anything like that?

Comment: I figured it out. Apart from verbose=true, debug=true setting in hgrc file causes issues too. Deleting that setting worked well with cloning the reps.

Comment: Great! Remember also to configure user access rights on hgrc to avoid errors during pushes!